# ZeroMQ PHP on Mac Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, mamp, zeromq, mamp-pro

I tried using ZeroMQ with PHP on a Mac OS Yosemite. I tried installing it through composer and below is the error message I keep getting

```
  Problem 1
- react/zmq v0.3.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is missing from your system.
- react/zmq v0.2.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is missing from your system.
- Installation request for react/zmq 0.2.*|0.3.* -> satisfiable by react/zmq[v0.2.0, v0.3.0].
```

From my observation, I feel I have to install the ZeroMQ PHP extension, but all efforts was abortive.
I also followed up with this link
http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2013/10/install-zeromq-on-mac-with-php-pecl-extension/
I'm running my server on MAMP3 for MAC OS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read this page?
There's the error message and the answer, how to solve it.

Comment: Stop using MAMP. Use Homebrew or Macports. After you have one of those installed then install php a webserver (I'd recommend apache or nginx) and whatever extensions and other binaries you need. Then install zmq extension. Then after all that install ZeroMQ via composer.

Comment: I have finally got it working by doing this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49654807/3815702

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to **install the software**: download current version and build on your system [here](http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software)

After this you need to **bind zmq library with php**: [here](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php) you can find a few ways to do it, usually I do it from github. Hope it helps

Comment: The second link has been removed and redirecting to homepage: https://zeromq.org/