# zeromq problems when installed via homebrew

Tags: php, macos

I am trying to install zeromq on a mac running `Sierra`. According to the installation guide http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software, you can install zeromq library by running:

```
brew install zmq
```

After successfull installation I proceded with adding `"react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*"` to the require section of the `composer.json` and running `composer install`

```
  Problem 1
    - react/zmq v0.3.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is missing from your system.
    - react/zmq v0.2.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for react/zmq 0.2.*|0.3.* -> satisfiable by react/zmq[v0.2.0, v0.3.0].
```

I think this has to do with macs having default php already installed and brew installing zeromq for the wrong php version. How should I debug this problem further?

`php -m` shows no `libzmg` package. `php -i` shows version `PHP Version => 5.6.30`. Inspecting `phpinfo()` in a browser also returns version `5.6.30`

Answer (score 2):

Well. I had finally found a way to do it.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq.git
$ cd php-zmq
$ phpize && ./configure
$ make && make install
```

Now you need find out which php.ini file is loaded on your CLI

```
$ php --ini
```

or you can find out by typing following command

```
$ php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

If not anything please add on on **"/etc/php.ini"**. I have added one, generally you have php.ini.default is present on "/etc" make a copy of that place in to **"/etc/php.ini"**

then you need find out the zmq.so file, you can find that by typing

```
$ sudo find / -name zmq.so
```

In case it is **/Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal/php-zmq/.libs/zmq.so**

So it will be "Path/TO/**php-zmq/.libs/zmq.so**"

Then edit your `php.ini` file and add the **exact path** of `zmq.so`

in my case "*extension=/Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal/php-zmq/.libs/zmq.so*"

```
extension=/$PATH_TO/php-zmq/.libs/zmq.so
```

All the best...

Comment: The repository files no longer work, at least when running PHP 7.3 on a Mac

Comment: Only the git url is not working (anymore); use `git clone git@github.com:zeromq/php-zmq.git` instead

Also, in my case, just adding `extension=zmq.so` (without the full path) worked as well

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Rakesh is correct but the repository no longer works, use https://github.com/alexat/php-zmq instead.